# JSON / struct column type in AWS GLUE + AWS Athena / Hive?

Tags: json, csv, hive, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a CSV file created from nested JSON. It has both regular type columns (e.g. int, string), as well as JSON columns, created from nested JSONs:

```
attributes;business_id;categories;city;days_open;latitude;longitude;name;review_count;stars;state
{"AcceptsInsurance": False, "AgesAllowed": "allages", "Alcohol": "beer_and_wine", "Ambience": {"casual": True, "classy": False, "divey": False, "hipster": False, "intimate": False, "romantic": False, "touristy": False, "trendy": False, "upscale": False}, "BYOB": False, "BikeParking": True, "BusinessAcceptsBitcoin": False, "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards": True, "BusinessParking": {"garage": False, "lot": False, "street": True, "valet": False, "validated": False}, "ByAppointmentOnly": False, "Caters": True, "CoatCheck": False, "Corkage": False, "DogsAllowed": False, "DriveThru": False, "GoodForDancing": False, "GoodForKids": False, "GoodForMeal": {"breakfast": False, "brunch": False, "dessert": False, "dinner": False, "latenight": False, "lunch": False}, "HappyHour": True, "HasTV": True, "Music": None, "NoiseLevel": "average", "Open24Hours": False, "OutdoorSeating": True, "RestaurantsAttire": "casual", "RestaurantsCounterService": False, "RestaurantsDelivery": False, "RestaurantsGoodForGroups": True, "RestaurantsPriceRange": 2, "RestaurantsReservations": False, "RestaurantsTableService": True, "RestaurantsTakeOut": True, "Smoking": "no", "WheelchairAccessible": True, "WiFi": "free"};6iYb2HFDywm3zjuRg0shjw;["Gastropubs", "Food", "Beer Gardens", "Restaurants", "Bars", "American (Traditional)", "Beer Bar", "Nightlife", "Breweries"];Boulder;["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];40.0175444;-105.2833481;Oskar Blues Taproom;86;4.0;CO
{"AcceptsInsurance": False, "AgesAllowed": "allages", "Alcohol": "beer_and_wine", "Ambience": {"casual": True, "classy": False, "divey": False, "hipster": False, "intimate": False, "romantic": False, "touristy": False, "trendy": False, "upscale": False}, "BYOB": False, "BikeParking": False, "BusinessAcceptsBitcoin": False, "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards": True, "BusinessParking": {"garage": True, "lot": False, "street": False, "valet": False, "validated": False}, "ByAppointmentOnly": False, "Caters": True, "CoatCheck": False, "Corkage": False, "DogsAllowed": False, "DriveThru": False, "GoodForDancing": False, "GoodForKids": True, "GoodForMeal": {"breakfast": True, "brunch": False, "dessert": False, "dinner": False, "latenight": False, "lunch": True}, "HappyHour": False, "HasTV": False, "Music": None, "NoiseLevel": "average", "Open24Hours": False, "OutdoorSeating": False, "RestaurantsAttire": "casual", "RestaurantsCounterService": False, "RestaurantsDelivery": False, "RestaurantsGoodForGroups": False, "RestaurantsPriceRange": 2, "RestaurantsReservations": False, "RestaurantsTableService": True, "RestaurantsTakeOut": True, "Smoking": "no", "WheelchairAccessible": False, "WiFi": "free"};tCbdrRPZA0oiIYSmHG3J0w;["Salad", "Soup", "Sandwiches", "Delis", "Restaurants", "Cafes", "Vegetarian"];Portland;["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];45.5889058992;-122.5933307507;Flying Elephants at PDX;126;4.0;OR
{"AcceptsInsurance": False, "AgesAllowed": "allages", "Alcohol": "none", "Ambience": None, "BYOB": False, "BikeParking": False, "BusinessAcceptsBitcoin": False, "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards": True, "BusinessParking": {"garage": False, "lot": False, "street": True, "valet": False, "validated": False}, "ByAppointmentOnly": False, "Caters": False, "CoatCheck": False, "Corkage": False, "DogsAllowed": False, "DriveThru": False, "GoodForDancing": False, "GoodForKids": False, "GoodForMeal": None, "HappyHour": False, "HasTV": False, "Music": None, "NoiseLevel": "average", "Open24Hours": False, "OutdoorSeating": False, "RestaurantsAttire": "casual", "RestaurantsCounterService": False, "RestaurantsDelivery": False, "RestaurantsGoodForGroups": False, "RestaurantsPriceRange": 2, "RestaurantsReservations": True, "RestaurantsTableService": True, "RestaurantsTakeOut": False, "Smoking": "no", "WheelchairAccessible": False, "WiFi": "no"};bvN78flM8NLprQ1a1y5dRg;["Antiques", "Fashion", "Used", "Vintage & Consignment", "Shopping", "Furniture Stores", "Home & Garden"];Portland;["Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];45.5119069956;-122.6136928797;The Reclaimory;13;4.5;OR
```

Can this file be processed with AWS Glue to be input for AWS Athena / Hive (which is used internally in Athena)? In particular, how can I specify the data type for JSON columns? Do I have to do this by hand? Are the JSONs written OK, or should they be reformatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will try to answer all of your questions.
*Can this file be processed with AWS Glue to be input for AWS Athena / Hive (which is used internally in Athena)?*
Should be. if you structure hive table properly, any csv file can be uploaded there.

*how can I specify the data type for JSON columns?*
in hive you can store as `string`. Looking at your json structure, you can easily access elements using expression like this - `get_json_object(json_col_str,'$.BusinessParking.garage')`.

*Do I have to do this by hand?*
I guess so unless you have some auto DDL creation utility. You can put sample rows in xl and find out the table structure easily.

*Are the JSONs written OK, or should they be reformatted?*
From the example you gave, i checked last row and json object seems fine to me. I also checked using https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ which validates and formats it in a pretty format. You can use it in case of any discrepancies.

Comment: Thank you, the 2nd question answer really cleared things for me!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to query this data with Athena as long as there are no semi-colons inside the JSON columns. Define your table as CSV with semi-colon as separator, and use `string` as the type of the JSON columns.

When you query this table you can use [the JSON functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/json.html) to query the JSON columns, for example:

```
SELECT json_extract_scalar(attributes, '$.AcceptsInsurance')
…
```